# CSS: Centered icon underneath a headline h1

Tags: css

I want to have a Centered icon arrow.gif underneath a single Word of the headline h1. my Problem is that this word is followed by other words. how can I place the icon directly under this word in a way it is centered to this single word.

Comment: By posting your code so we can play with it.

Comment: Please post the code that you already have. You most likely won't get any help if you don't show us what you have or have already tried.

Comment: Why not give them a chance to edit / add some code before down voting them off of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, I play around with pseudo element :before and :after . here is an Example, ... http://jsfiddle.net/9e27b/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. but be careful. It's very limited if you have more workds or multiple lines.

```css
.u-table {
    display: table !important;
}

.u-table-cell {
    display: table-cell !important;
}

.u-text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="u-table">
    <span class="u-table-cell u-text-center">Word 1<br/><img src="" alt="Foo"></span>
    <span class="u-table-cell">word 2</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you this is a nice example.